# Elessar - configuring range slider labels

Tags: javascript, range, date-range, elessar

I would like to use the [Elessar](http://quarterto.github.io/Elessar/) library, and configure it to select multiple hour ranges (of a single day). like so:

[image]

This kind of looks right, but obviously the "a few seconds" ranges are incorrect. Here is my current configuration:

```
min: moment([2007, 0, 29]),
max: moment([2007, 0, 30]),
valueFormat: function(ts) {
  return moment(ts).format('LT');
},
valueParse: function(date) {
  return moment(date).valueOf();
},
label: function(a){
  return moment(a[1]).from(a[0], true);
},
snap: 1000 * 60 * 15,
minSize: 1000 * 60 * 60,
barClass: 'progress',
rangeClass: 'bar',
maxRanges: 3,
bgLabels: 12
```

Any ideas how to fix the range labels?

Comment: Note that the `label` function is being passed already formatted values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer is a little late but....

```
label: function(a) { 
    var from =  moment(a[0]);
    var until =  moment(a[1]);
    return from.format('HH:mm') + ' to ' + until.format('HH:mm');
}
```